# Testing a URL with a parameter in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to test a URL via a Go function. In our environment, we have our hostnames set up per environment, like `https://www/examplesite20193.domain.org` Here is a simple example of what I've got:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    versionMaj := "2019"
    versionMin := "3"
    endpoint := versionMaj+versionMin
    
    resp, err:= http.Get("https://www.examplesite%s.domain.org", endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))
}
```

When I test this, it's stating `too many arguments in call to http.Get have (string, string) want (string)`.
Is there a way to pass in a parameter, like the endpoint one I have specified?

Comment: Use fmt.Sprintf to construct the URL.

Comment: Test a URL with a parameter by providing a URL with a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're looking to something like this:

```
resp, err:= http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.examplesite%s.domain.org", endpoint))
```